# Fill a table based on multiple positions in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. One is:

```
Age,Name,Dog,Cat,House,Car,Food

12,'Bob',0,0,0,0,0

12,'Sam',0,0,0,0,0

18,'Sam',0,0,0,0,0
```

And I have a much longer table

```
Age,Name,Item,Amount

12,'Bob','Dog',1

12,'Bob','Cat',3

12,'Sam','Cat',1

18,'Sam','Cat',1

18,'Sam','House',3
```

Final product:

```
Age,Name,Dog,Cat,House,Car,Food

12,'Bob',1,0,0,0,0

12,'Sam',0,1,0,0,0

18,'Sam',0,1,3,0,0
```

Basically I have to fill the first table up with values in the second table.
I have to match the age and name from the first to the second table, then see which one of the 1st tables columns I'm given in the second table, and fill in the amount

I've hardcoded it using three & conditions, but I have millions of rows/columns so it will literally take days to run if I do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need your first df just use `pivot_table` on df2:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# your sample data
s2 = """Age,Name,Item,Amount

12,'Bob','Dog',1

12,'Bob','Cat',3

12,'Sam','Cat',1

18,'Sam','Cat',1

18,'Sam','House',3"""

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s2), quotechar="'")


# use pivot_table to reshape your dataFrame and reset your index
df2.pivot_table('Amount', ['Age', 'Name'], 'Item', aggfunc=sum).reset_index()

Item  Age Name  Cat  Dog  House
0      12  Bob  3.0  1.0    NaN
1      12  Sam  1.0  NaN    NaN
2      18  Sam  1.0  NaN    3.0
```

Or just use `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
df2.groupby(['Age', 'Name', 'Item'])['Amount'].sum().unstack().reset_index()

Item  Age Name  Cat  Dog  House
0      12  Bob  3.0  1.0    NaN
1      12  Sam  1.0  NaN    NaN
2      18  Sam  1.0  NaN    3.0
```

For the first example, just change `aggfunc` to whatever function you want to use to handle multiple values and same for `groupby` change `.sum()` to whatever function you want.

## An update to answer your real question: replace values in a df:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# your sample data

s = """Age,Name,Dog,Cat,House,Car,Food

12,'Bob',0,0,0,0,0

12,'Sam',0,0,0,0,0

18,'Sam',0,0,0,0,0"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), quotechar="'")

s2 = """Age,Name,Item,Amount

12,'Bob','Dog',1

12,'Bob','Cat',3

12,'Sam','Cat',1

18,'Sam','Cat',1

18,'Sam','House',3"""

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s2), quotechar="'")


# use pivot_table to reshape your dataFrame
pivot = df2.pivot_table('Amount', ['Age', 'Name'], 'Item', aggfunc=sum)

# set the index to age and name and create a new df
df1 = df1.set_index(['Age', 'Name'])

# use update to replace values
df1.update(pivot)
print(df1.reset_index())

   Age Name  Dog  Cat  House  Car  Food
0   12  Bob  1.0  3.0    0.0    0     0
1   12  Sam  0.0  1.0    0.0    0     0
2   18  Sam  0.0  1.0    3.0    0     0
```

Comment: Dude, thanks a ton! It doesn't do it in the way I wanted it done (ie, what's a fastest way to multi replace columns based on multiple other columns), but it gets the job done regardless for this case. Thanks again.

Comment: @roushrsh I added an update that answers your question on multi replace columns based on another DataFrame